# Хранимая процедура для группировки номеров

Tags: postgresql, sql

Есть таблица с номерами http://dl1.joxi.net/drive/0004/3643/302651/141016/046b8a208c.jpg.   Нужно получить список, содержащий непрерывные диапазоны.

Т.е. если номера идут списком 4525345345345345,4525345345345346,4525345345345347 группируется в диапазон 4525345345345345-4525345345345347, далее следующий диапазон. Если номер в диапазоне один, то передается одним номером.

Есть какие-то типовые примеры реализации такой задачи или соображения, как написать?

Comment: Числа в таблице всегда идут по возрастанию? Т.е. может быть, например, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6?

Comment: нет, но перед какими либо выборками можно произвести сортировку записей

Comment: А каким образом (планируется) эти ХП вызывать? Желаемый пример вызова в студию!

Comment: @pgsql190, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

У меня получилось вот так:

```
WITH R (N, RN) AS
(
    SELECT
        TT.N
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N) RN
    FROM
        tmp_table TT
)
SELECT
    R.N start_periaod
    ,(
        SELECT
            MAX(R1.N)
        FROM
            R R1
        WHERE
            R1.N > R.N
            AND (R1.N - R.N) = (R1.RN - R.RN)
    ) end_period
FROM
    R
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            R R2
        WHERE
            (R.N - R2.N) = 1
    )
```